# Expo fonts loadAsync not working in specific device React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, expo

I'm using loadAsync to load some fonts. It worked fine while testing the app on my device, but when I tried on another device (Galaxy s10e), the fonts seem to be loaded (checking with Font.isLoaded) but not displaying when using fontFamily.

This is my App.js

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
import React, {useState} from 'react';



const fetchFonts = async() => {
  return await Font.loadAsync ({
    secular: require ('./assets/fonts/SecularOne-Regular.ttf'),
    varela: require ('./assets/fonts/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf'),
    lemon: require ('./assets/fonts/LemonMilk.otf'),
    collegiate: require ('./assets/fonts/CollegiateBlackFLF.ttf'),
    assistant: require ('./assets/fonts/Assistant-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    zvulun: require ('./assets/fonts/zvulun-black-fm.otf'),
    roboto: require ('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
    osh: require ('./assets/fonts/OpenSansHebrew-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    oshregular: require ('./assets/fonts/OpenSansHebrew-Regular.ttf'),
    oshlight: require('./assets/fonts/OpenSansHebrew-Light.ttf'),
    myriad: require('./assets/fonts/myriad-hebrew.ttf')
  });
};



export default function App () {
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState (false);

  if (!dataLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={() => fetchFonts().then(() => console.log('done')).catch((err) => console.log(err))}
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded (true)}
        onError={err => console.log (err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return *the actual app*;
}
```

To be clear, the fonts do load and show correctly on another device (Galaxy s10+).
Expo SDK 37
Android 11
expo-font 8.1.0